# Deletion repeated rows of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix that some rows of this matrix are repeated two times.

I need to delete repeated rows to get a fullrank matrix, that I can do this with a loop.

BUT is there anyone who know any function in matlab that do this ?

Please hint me.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is not about mathematics, but about Matlab programming and is thus off-topic for this site. In the future, an appropriate place to ask such a question might be [Stackoverflow Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html (read about the 'rows' and 'stable' options).